# возможны ли такие первичные ключи?

Tags: sql, база-данных

База данных «Тату салон» должна хранить информацию о записи к мастерам на сеансы татуировки. Требуется хранить данные:

1. О тату-мастерах (ФИО, дата рождения, паспорт, номер медкнижки, дата последнего медосмотра, стаж).
2. Об эскизах (Название, дата создания, мастер, стоимость эскиза).
3. Об услугах (Название, описание, минимальная длительность, стоимость за расходные материалы).
4. О записи к тату-мастерам на услуги с указанием даты и времени записи и эскиза, если он имеется.

Правильно ли будет использовать вот такие ключи?

1. номер медкнижки
2. название
3. название

Answer (score 1):

Для учебного задания можно, но для реальной БД я бы не рекомендовал использовать их в качестве первичных, по следующим причинам:

1. первичный ключ не должен меняться, а, например, медкнижка имеет срок годности.
2. Строки для внешних ключей (FK) требуют большего расхода памяти, чем суррогатные ключи.

Я бы сделал их альтернативными ключами (UNQUE), но первичные почти всегда лучше делать суррогатными.